# sha1 is hashing nothing, how do I stop it from doing this?

Tags: php, sql, sha1

This is the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$valid = true;



//Check for first name value
if (empty($_POST['texts'])) {
    echo 'You forgot to type something in<br />';
    $valid = false;
}

if ($valid == true) {
    $conn1 = mysqli_connect('xxx') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    $name=   $_POST['name'];
    $title=  sha1($_POST['title']);
    $texts= $_POST['texts'];
    $forum_id = $_POST['forum_id'];




        $name = str_replace("'","''",$name);
        $title = str_replace("'","''",$title);
        $title = str_replace("b074acd521","STREAMER",$title);

        $texts = str_replace("'","''",$texts);


        $title = substr($title,0,8);


        $sql = "INSERT INTO post (name,title, texts, forum_id) VALUES ('$name', '$title', '$texts', '$forum_id')";
        mysqli_query($conn1, $sql) or die('Error inserting to database.');
        mysqli_close($conn1);

        header('Location: requests.php');
        }
else {
    echo 'Click <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">HERE</a> to go back and adjust your entry.';
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I make a post on the site and leave the id field empty it still generates an ID, how can I fix this? Also, if the name field is empty how can I make it default to a something?

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code inline here (by editing your question). As it stands, your question has zero lasting value as soon as that pastebin link goes dead.

Comment: Don't see any sha1 reference in your code

Comment: $title=  sha1($_POST['title']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (if not all) hashing algorithms will hash an empty string.  If they didn't, they wouldn't really be "honest" hashes. The idea is that you shouldn't be able to decipher the hash to the original input. For example, if the following:

```
All good boys deserve fudge!
```

and

```
All good boys deserve  fudge!
```

used a hash algorithm that treated empty space as unhashable, then they would get the same hash, which would make it easier to crack.

If you don't want empty strings to be hashed, you need to check the string before hashing it. Something like:

```
 if(!empty($_POST['user_input']) {
      $user_hash = sha1($_POST['user_input']);
 } else {
      echo "No input given, wiseguy!";
 }
```